# SQL: How to get the following day from end of the month

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example:

If I run this query today (26 January), my result will be addedon +1 day which is 27 January.

```
select addedon 
from member
Where Day(addedon) = Day(DateAdd(dd, 1, GetDate()))
and Month(addedon) = Month(DateAdd(dd, 1, GetDate()))
```

However, when  I run this query on 31 January, it is giving me 1 January result instead of 1 Feb.

Please help! Note that I can only use simple select statement (like the above) in my application.

Answer (score 1):

To get the beginning of the next month:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)
```

This will return `member` whose `addedon` falls on the first day of the next month.

```
SELECT addedon
FROM member
WHERE
    addedon >= DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)
    AND addedon < DATEADD(DD, 1, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0))
```

This will return `member` whose `addedon`falls on the next day:

```
SELECT addedon
FROM #member
WHERE
    addedon >= DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)
    AND addedon < DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, GETDATE()) + 2, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that your `datetime` are - as is pretty typical - stored in your database as UTC `datetime`, and that you are somewhere in the Western Hemisphere, and that calling `Month` on a UTC time after, say, 9:30EDT (or 8:30CDT) is returning `2`, matching `Month(DateAdd(dd, 1, GetDate()))`.

Most of the time, you want to store your `datetime` in your database as UTC, which means - most of the time - you want to write your queries the same way (i.e., using `GetUtcDate`).

As a test, rewrite you query using `GetUtcDate` in place of `GetDate`, and see if your results change.

Comment: This is a great point, check the type of data you are working with and it can give you insight to how to solve your problem.